# How to Embed Variable in Attribute String

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my `Form.aspx` page, I have the following line in `Page_Load`:

`userName = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Split('\\')[1];`

And I am using the following line to set some text on the form itself:

`userLabelSecret.Text = $"Hello {userName}. Please enter a secret word or phrase:";`

---

I would like to do something like this in the form instead:

`<asp:Label ID="userLabelSecret" runat="server" Text="Hello <%=userName%>. Please enter a secret word or phrase: "></asp:Label>`

However, this just shows the string `<%=userName%>` rather than the actual `userName` variable.

Is it possible to embed the variable in the `Text` attribute like this, instead of assigning it in `Page_Load`?

---

I tried doing this will the normal C# concatenation operator (`+`) but this causes the following error:

`<asp:Label ID="userLabelSecret" runat="server" Text= "Hello " + <%=userName%> + ". Please enter a secret word or phrase: "></asp:Label>`

`The name 'userLabelSecret' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Have you already changed Label ID from `userSecretLabel` to `userLabelSecret`? Refactor both designer and code behind .cs file to match Label ID in aspx page if you don't sure.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Sorry, that was a typo! the only label I have is `userLabelSecret`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that cannot be done. Also embedding code in mark-up is not a good practice.

Still if thats the route you want to take, the below steps will achieve the same result for you.

Make userName a public property. Then change the asp:label to just `<label>` and do something like:

```
<label>Hello <%=userName%>. Please enter a secret word or phrase:</label>
```

Comment: Thank you - if embedding code in the html is seen as bad practice I will just opt for changing it with a `Label.Text="texthere";`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating directly by "+" operator inside asp:Label, try to use `String.Concat`:

```
<asp:Label ID="userLabelSecret" runat="server" Text= "<%= String.Concat("Hello ", userName, ". Please enter a secret word or phrase: ") %>"></asp:Label>
```

or plain HTML server control with similar functionality and keeping server control's name:

```
<label id="userLabelSecret" runat="server">Hello <%= userName %>. Please enter a secret word or phrase:</label>
```

CMIIW.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to have one property of type string

property string username{get;set;}

property string text {get;set;}=string.Format("Hello {0}. Please enter a secret word or phrase:",username)

+ ". Please enter a secret word or phrase: ">